# I am facing a issue relted to custom url in 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, error, url-rewrite, log

After every **Re-Indexing** from admin panel one of the category url is changed in this manner.

before Re-Index : cushion-covers **-9**.html
After Re-Index : cushion-covers **-11**.html

and its changing from cushion-covers-2.html

**What I am thinking is.**

Can I truncate **core_url_rewrite** (so that it becomes totally empty)
and re-index again. Is it good solution. (My consern is does it harm any functionality ).

Kindly suggest can  i do this or any better solution.

**UPDATE**

I tried above method but it start again from **cushion-covers-2.html**

what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can truncate core_url_rewrite and re-index again, before you please take backup of your database for safer side.

Run this below Query or TRUNCATE manually

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Before you do anything

> > Make sure you test clearing this data in a non-production environment first.
> >
> > Always make backups before you lose data forever.
> >
> > Make sure you're truncating, not droping.
> >
> > Probably a good idea to re-index everything via shell after mass deleting records.

Comment: I did that , and re-index the magneto , but nothing changed in url.